# I need to get value from data in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have a value what I want in one method but I can't getting in fetchdata function.

```
<script>    
export default {
    name: 'TaxMain',
    data () {
        return {
            detail:{
                tax_identifier: '',
                tax_id: '',
            }
        }           
    },
    methods: {
        readTax(taxId) {
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token'); 
            axios.post(baseUrl+'/tax/detail',{'taxId':taxId})
            .then((response) => {
                if((typeof(response) != 'undefined')&& (typeof(response.data) != 'undefined') &&(typeof(response.data.form) != 'undefined')){
                     this.detail = response.data.form;
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                return Promise.reject(error)
            });
        },
        async fetchData ({search, page, filter, sort,rows}) {               
            alert(this.detail.tax_id);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The function readTax contain the tax_id, that tax_id I want to access in fetchData. Now it shows only blank because of tax_id in data is null now. How to access it?

Comment: It seems to me that You are probably calling fetchData right before the readTax has been completely executed

Comment: Your code is a bit of a mess.  Your method names seem to be switched around (readTax is fetching data, fetch data seem to read tax_id). Also, a lot of parameters are missing.